# Blazor: Why does first call to NavigateTo destroy scoped services in production?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I am trying to use Blazor to make a website. This bug doesn't occur on IIS Express or from localhost on IIS, but when hosting on an external website I always encounter this issue. The first time I use NavigateTo right off the first page, all of my services are reinitialized.

If I use a NavLink in the default sample app's NavMenu to leave the first page, or if I've already navigated away from or back to the index page at least once, the services maintain their state.

I checked my services right before the NavigateTo was called and they had values, but they're all lost after it executes. Singletons maintain their state.

To isolate the bug, I've created this barely modified Blazor Server app and included the changed code snippets below.

In Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddSingleton<ConfigAccess>();
    services.AddScoped<BasicService>();
}
```

Index.razor:

```
@page "/"
@using Blazor_Bug_Isolation_Test.Services
@inject BasicService Basic
@inject ConfigAccess ConfigAccess
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

<input @bind="Basic.Zipcode" placeholder="Postal code..." />
<input type="radio" @onclick="() => Basic.Option = BasicService.Options.Yes" name="options" id="yes"/>
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" @onclick="() => Basic.Option = BasicService.Options.No" name="options" id="no" value="0" />
<label for="no">No</label>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick='() => navigationManager.NavigateTo(ConfigAccess.ApplicationRoot + "/Next")'>Proceed</button>
```

Next.razor:

```
@page "/Next"
@using Blazor_Bug_Isolation_Test.Services
@inject BasicService Basic
@inject ConfigAccess ConfigAccess
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

<p>
    Zipcode: @Basic.Zipcode
</p>
<p>
    Radio: @Basic.Option
</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick='() => navigationManager.NavigateTo(ConfigAccess.ApplicationRoot + "/Last")'>Last</button>
```

And BasicService.cs

```
namespace Blazor_Bug_Isolation_Test.Services
{
    public class BasicService
    {
        public Options Option { get; set; }
        public string Zipcode { get; set; }

        public enum Options
        {
            Yes = 1,
            No = 2
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, a screenshot of my file layout.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R98Rt.png)

I could also include the code for ConfigAccess if requested, but the application root uses a custom getter, so it always evaluates to the right address.

Any input saved to a service is lost the first time I click Proceed from Index.razor. If anyone knows why, I would really appreciate any help.

**UPDATE:** It appears the first navigateto causes the websocket to be dropped and reestablished, which explains why scoped services are reconstructed. I still have no idea what's causing that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Can you temporarily publish your test site to Github and send me a link.  From your description I would suggest that the problem is in the URL you are creating in `NavigateTo`.  `NavigateTo` doesn't actually do a lot, it just fires the `LocationChanged` event.  The Router is wired into this and does the hard work. It's treating the URL you are constructing as outside it's routing scope, and doing a hard navigation rather than simply loading a new component into `app`.

Triple check what `ConfigAccess.ApplicationRoot + "/Last"` is creating.

Answer (score 0):

set second parameter of NavigateTo to false and it will work

Comment: Interesting. I haven't touched this project in a while, but I'll dig it up to test that.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't cut it. It looks like the second parameter, Force, defaults to false.